# success function not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a ajax call to get a record from the database I have seen in the console that it is successfully returning the record but success is function is not being executed.

```
function ajaxForParent() {
    var search = document.getElementById("resourceId").value;
    var folderId = document.getElementById("folderId").value;

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : "/admin/content/changeParent",
        data : {search : search, folderId : folderId}, // Note it is important
        success : function(folder) {
            alert(folder);
            if (folder.id == document.getElementById("folderId").value) {
                $("#parentAvailable").html("Children Limit exceeding you cannot add more than 9 levels children");
                return false;
            }

            console.log(folder.id);
            console.log(document.getElementById("folderId").value);

            if (folder.id != document.getElementById("folderId").value) {
                console.log("I am coming here " +folder.id);
                var s = document.getElementById("folderId");
                s.value = folder.id;
            }
            $("#parentAvailable").html("Parent Found Successfully!");
        },
        error : function(content) {
            $("#parentAvailable").html("Parent Not available");
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried with the above it always entering the error function even though record is successfully return from server side. can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

when I throw the error I am getting this

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 1587309 of the JSON data`

Comment: check the html status code, make sure the response has a `200 OK` status

Comment: @UriGoren - Yeah I am getting 200 OK status

Comment: the error suggests that the returned JSON is not valid.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli is right, could you attach the server's response to the question ?

Comment: @UriGoren - I have tested the data that is coming in it is not the correct JSON format.

Comment: That error indicates bad json format, you can run `JSON.parse()` on it with a console, and verify that. from my experience it is usually a quoting issue

Answer (score 3):

You cannot send `json` data via **GET**.
You need to use **POST**:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST", // <------ Use POST 
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : "/admin/content/changeParent",
    data : {search : search, folderId : folderId},
```

If your app `/admin/content/changeParent` accepts only GET, you may need to consider changing it to accept POST. Otherwise, your app cannot receive the JSON data you send to the server correctly via GET.

Comment: what ? offcourse you can use the `json` format with get, there is even a shorthand for that `$.getJSON()`

Comment: @Tao  - If I use the Post then how can I get the data which is coming back from the server ?

Comment: The response from the server can be of any format including JSON. No matter which HTTP verb you use, you will receive the response back from the server.

Comment: @UriGoren what you mentioned was getting a JSON response, not "sending JSON".

Comment: @TaoP.R. run this script in your console `jQuery.get('/',{'q':'r'})`, it is automatically translated to a `GET` request for `/?q=r`, `jQuery` can handle these kind of conversions automatically

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response contains improperly formatted json data. Try copying the response into a json linter such as http://jsonlint.com/ to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

take your server answer and paste it into some json linter (like http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure jquery can transform it to a valid response.

you can also put a breakpoint into your error callback and check for the error and value returned at that moment. While you're there, if the data received is a string and not an object, try to call JSON.parse(/* your server response */) to test if it's working at all and if you get any additional error.

Comment: this should be a comment, not a solution

Comment: only 41 reputation, can't comment ;)